# How to set up Dial-Up and VNP on Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, networking

I wasn't able to find a way to make my connection work on Ubuntu.
It's not an usual type of connection so I was not able to find in anywhere.
For me to be able to use this type of internet connection i have to be Connected to wireless "Zone Gvozdac" (Done that).After I'm connected to that I need to connect to an
Dial-Up/VNP connection.On windows you only have to type 3 things:
-System Name (Display name or whatever it's called)
-Username
-Password
Hope I hear from you soon.
[right]~Chears[/right]

Comment: We would really need to know what kind of VPN it is to help you.  Ubuntu supports PPPT VPNs out of the box but other types might require you to install specific software.

Comment: It's Wireless PPPoE.....

Answer (score 0):

First get connected to the wireless connection you have available.
Second click on the network connection icon on the top tool bar where you would have connected to the wireless network. There should be an option for VPN Connections. Choose configure VPN connections. If you see PPPT there already you can edit the connection to match the login info you have.  If you do not see it there use the add option to add it.  Fill in all the fields you have information for and leave the rest at their default settings.